# Limit access to a page

Tags: date, user-registration, limit

I try to limit access to a page only for registered users before a specific date.
For the others, a message must be display.

Here is my code

```
    <?php if( strtotime( $user->user_registered ) < mktime( 0, 0, 0, 3, 7, 2016 ) ) {
echo do_shortcode('[gravityform id=14]');
}
else {
    echo "Désolé. La participation est réservée aux membres inscrits avant le 07 mars 2016.";
}
?>
```

Actually, this code display the gravityform even if registration date is taller than mktime value.
I want to display the message "Désolé. La participation est réservée aux membres inscrits avant le 07 mars 2016." for users registered after 2616/03/06.

How can i do it ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry. Find by myself. Just forget to declare $user = wp_get_current_user();

Comment: If you found the answer it is best to add it as an answer then choose it as best answer so this thread can be marked as answered :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Find by myself. Just forget to declare `$user = wp_get_current_user();`